# Draw 3x3 square grid in R

Tags: r, r-grid

I got a list of number (n=9) and would like to draw them out in a 3*3 square grid and each grid fill with corresponding number. How can I do this in R without installing additional package e.g. plotrix. Many thanks!

[image: pic]

Comment: with base graphics, you'll need to combine `plot.new()` and `plot.window()` (or `plot(...,type="n")`, `segments()` and `text()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a good solution using just base R, and outputting to a png.  Note the default `png` device has equal width and height.

```
png("magic_square.png")
par(mar=c(.5,.5,.5,.5))
plot(x=df$x,y=df$y,pch=as.character(df$val), 
     asp=1, xlim=c(0.5,3.5),ylim=c(0.5,3.5),xaxt="n",yaxt="n",xlab="",ylab="",
xaxs="i", yaxs="i", axes=F)
abline(v=0.5+(0:3),h=0.5+(0:3))
dev.off()
```

You can use `cex` in the `plot` call to make the numbers appear larger.

And you can add circles as follows.  Note the abline locations.

```
symbols(1.5,1.5,circles=1,add=TRUE)
```

And to annotate as shown in the comment, set the background of the circle and use `points` to draw additional text annotations.

```
symbols(1.5,1.5,circles=1,bg="white",add=TRUE)
text(x=1.5,y=1.5,labels="17",cex=3)
```

Of course the real key to doing this well will be mastering the data structures to make calls into `plot`, `symbols`, and `text` efficient.

[image: sample output]

Comment: You can use `xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i", axes = F` inside the call to plot for a nicer output.

Comment: thanks a lot! i am trying to see how to set the length of those ablines now :)

Comment: also any advice on if i want to add circle in the middle of (8,1,3,5)? Many thanks!

Comment: How should the circle be placed? Like one single circle on that corner? Or a circle around each number? See edited answer.

Comment: @alexis_laz thanks for the helpful tips there. Really cleaned up the output.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a `ggplot` solution that was a little harder than I expected:

```
# Setup the data
m <- matrix(c(8,3,4,1,5,9,6,7,2), nrow=3, ncol=3)
df <- expand.grid(x=1:ncol(m),y=1:nrow(m))
df$val <- m[as.matrix(df[c('y','x')])]

library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, label=val)) + 
  geom_tile(fill='transparent', colour = 'black') + 
  geom_text(size = 14) + 
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text  = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: @RichardScriven Ugh. Thanks for letting me know, I'll give up now.

Comment: This will look especially nice if you add `coord_fixed()`.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one using `plotrix` (sorry, but it's much easier if you use a package!) and @nograpes's `df` data.

```
library(plotrix)
xt <- xtabs(val ~ ., df[c(2,1,3)])
color2D.matplot(xt, vcex = 3, show.values = 1, axes = FALSE, xlab = "",   
                ylab = "", cellcolors = rep("white", length(xt)))
```

[image]

In case other answers ever change, `df` was constructed with

```
m <- matrix(c(8,3,4,1,5,9,6,7,2), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
df <- expand.grid(x = 1:ncol(m),y = 1:nrow(m))
df$val <- m[as.matrix(df[c('y', 'x')])]
```

Comment: Nice option with the `color2D.matplot` (+1)

Comment: Nice example of using plotrix. I found that using `show.values=1`  produced values with 1 decimal as per the documentation, e.g 1.0, and setting this to 0 showed no values. However any setting of `show.values` between 0 and 1 displays integer values as shown above. I suspect this is bit of a hack so it may be unreliable.