# R: matrix with directional arrows

Tags: r, symbols, reinforcement-learning

I am trying to reproduce with R an algorithm described in Sutton and Barto (2018), but I was not able to produce a matrix with arrows as the one described by the authors on page 65:

[image]

I tried to use the package "fields" for this purpose, but without much success.

In Python the solution proposed by Shangtong Zhang and Kenta Shimada
relies on using the arrows symbols:
ACTIONS_FIGS=[ '←', '↑', '→', '↓']
but this does not work nicely with R...

EDIT: I coded the initial actions and the action updates numerically as follows:

```
library(data.table)
action_random = data.table(cell=c(1:25))
action_random$action_up = action_random$action_right = action_random$action_down =
action_random$action_left = rep(1,25)
action_random$proba = rep(1/4,25)
action_random
```

I was also able to adapt the code posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27030055/draw-3x3-square-grid-in-r), to draw a simple grid with simple arrows:

```
arrows = matrix(c("\U2190","\U2191","\U2192","\U2193"),nrow=2,ncol=2)
grid_arrows = expand.grid(x=1:ncol(arrows),y=1:nrow(arrows))
grid_arrows$val = arrows[as.matrix(grid_arrows[c('y','x')])]

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(grid_arrows, aes(x=x, y=y, label=val)) + 
  geom_tile(fill='transparent', colour = 'black') + 
  geom_text(size = 14) + 
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(axis.text  = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank())
```

However:
(i) There is no unicode available for the nice 2 are 4-directional arrows reported in Table $\pi_\ast$ above
(ii) ... and so I was not trying to code the bijection between the numerical values in the Table "action_random" and a nice Table with arrows in it...

Any hint helping to resolve issues (i) and (ii) are welcome.

Comment: Maybe you should some your relevant code.

Comment: @nbro: I added an edit with a short example on how I coded the actions numerically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a grid+lattice way to reproduce the matrix:

```
library(grid)
library(lattice)

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(viewport(width = 0.8, height = 0.8)) 
grid.rect(width = 1, height = 1)
panel.grid(h = 4, v = 4)

direct = function(xCenter, yCenter, type){
  
  d= 0.05
  
  north = function(xCenter, yCenter){ 
    grid.curve(xCenter, yCenter-d ,xCenter, yCenter+d, 
               ncp = 1, angle = 90, gp=gpar(lwd=1, fill="black"),
               inflect = FALSE, shape = 0,
               arrow = arrow(type="closed", ends = "last", 
                      angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, "cm")))}
  
  west = function(xCenter, yCenter){
    grid.curve(xCenter+d, yCenter ,xCenter-d, yCenter, 
               ncp = 1, angle = 90, gp=gpar(lwd=1, fill="black"),
               inflect = FALSE, shape = 0,
               arrow = arrow(type="closed", ends = "last", 
                             angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, "cm")))}
  east = function(xCenter, yCenter){
    grid.curve(xCenter+d, yCenter ,xCenter-d, yCenter, 
               ncp = 1, angle = 90, gp=gpar(lwd=1, fill="black"),
               inflect = FALSE, shape = 0,
               arrow = arrow(type="closed", ends = "first", 
                             angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, "cm")))}
  
  northeast = function(xCenter, yCenter){
       grid.curve(xCenter-d, yCenter+d ,xCenter+d, yCenter-d, 
                 ncp = 1, angle = 90, gp=gpar(lwd=1, fill="black"),
                 inflect = FALSE, shape = 0,
                 arrow = arrow(type="closed", ends = "both", 
                         angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, "cm")))}
  
  northwest = function(xCenter, yCenter){
       grid.curve(xCenter-d, yCenter-d ,xCenter+d, yCenter+d, 
               ncp = 1, angle = 90, gp=gpar(lwd=1, fill="black"),
               inflect = FALSE, shape = 0,
               arrow = arrow(type="closed", ends = "both", 
                             angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, "cm")))}
  all = function(xCenter, yCenter){
      grid.curve(xCenter+d, yCenter ,xCenter-d, yCenter, 
                 ncp = 1, angle = 90, gp=gpar(lwd=1, fill="black"),
                 inflect = FALSE, shape = 0,
                 arrow = arrow(type="closed", ends = "both", 
                               angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, "cm")))
      grid.curve(xCenter, yCenter-d ,xCenter, yCenter+d, 
             ncp = 1, angle = 90, gp=gpar(lwd=1, fill="black"),
             inflect = FALSE, shape = 0,
             arrow = arrow(type="closed", ends = "both", 
                           angle = 30, length = unit(0.2, "cm")))}
  switch(type,
         'n' = north(xCenter, yCenter),
         'e' = east(xCenter, yCenter),
         'w' = west(xCenter, yCenter),
         'nw'= northwest(xCenter, yCenter),
         'ne' = northeast(xCenter, yCenter),
         'all' = all(xCenter, yCenter)
         )
}

x = seq(0.1, 0.9, by = 0.2)
y = x
centers = expand.grid(x0 = x, y0 = y)

row1 = row2 = row3 = c('ne','n', rep('nw',3))
row4 = c('ne','n','nw','w','w')
row5 = c('e','all','w','all','w')

dir = c(row1,row2,row3,row4,row5)
df = data.frame(centers, dir)

for (k in 1:nrow(df)) direct(df$x0[k], df$y0[k], df$dir[k])
grid.text(bquote(~pi["*"]), y = -0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice grid. Thank you for your post which also allows me to discover the grid package.

Comment: Glad if it helps. The {grid} and {lattice} packages are among base R packages, included in every release of R installer so you don't need to install them manually using 'install.packages()'

Answer (score 7):

Using the package `emojifont` works for me to get more unicode options. In your ggplot you add `family='EmojiOne'`. Here is an example using the unicode

[More about the package emojifont here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emojifont/vignettes/emojifont.html)

**EDIT**: Hack for 4-directional arrow:

Not the prettiest or more elegant solution, but you can overlay ggplots using the package `magick`  to get directional arrows. Make two plot layers, one with left-right arrow (`U+2194`) and another with up-down arrow (`U+2195`), then merge then (thanks @Billy34 for making the code a bit more elegant):

```
library(data.table)
library(magick)

library(ggplot2)
library(emojifont)

#layer 1
arrows1 = matrix(c("\U21B4","\U2195","\U2192","\U2193"),nrow=2,ncol=2)
grid_arrows1 = expand.grid(x=1:ncol(arrows1),y=1:nrow(arrows1))
grid_arrows1$val = arrows1[as.matrix(grid_arrows1[c('y','x')])]

#layer 2
arrows2 = matrix(c("\U21B4","\U2194","\U2192","\U2193"),nrow=2,ncol=2)
grid_arrows2 = expand.grid(x1=1:ncol(arrows2),y1=1:nrow(arrows2))
grid_arrows2$val = arrows2[as.matrix(grid_arrows2[c('y1','x1')])]

ggplot(grid_arrows1, aes(x=x, y=y, label=val),family='EmojiOne') + 
  geom_tile(fill='NA', colour = 'black') + 
  
  geom_text(size = 18) + 
  
  geom_text(grid_arrows2,mapping =  aes(x=x1, y=y1, label=val),size = 18) +
  scale_y_reverse() +
  theme_classic() + 
  theme(
        panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"), # bg of the panel
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA), # bg of the plot
axis.text  = element_blank(),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        axis.line  = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks = element_blank(),
        axis.title = element_blank()# get rid of legend panel bg
  ) 
  
#save plot as image
ggsave(filename = 'plot1.png', device = 'png', bg = 'transparent') 


# read images with package magick
 plot1 <- image_read('plot1.png')

image_mosaic(plot1)
```

[image]

UPDATE:

Just as ungracious as the previous code, but closer to what you are looking for…

Certain Unicodes work only with certain fonts, so the first step is to find which fonts work for the Unicode you are looking for. Here is an example of font support for a type of [leftwards arrow used in the example below](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1f800/fontsupport.htm).

Of course, none of the fonts on the list is standard, because life is not that easy. So the next step is install the font. I used font *Symbola* that I downloaded [here](https://fontlibrary.org/en/font/symbola). Copy the font file to your R directory or to your project folder if you are using projects.

Then use the library [showtext](https://journal.r-project.org/archive/2015/RJ-2015-008/RJ-2015-008.pdf). The package allow you to use system fonts in graphics (requires package `sysfonts`). If the font is standard in your OS I recommend you look at the package [systemfonts](https://github.com/r-lib/systemfonts).

In my example I used the arrows `\U1F800` and `\U1F801`, then, like in my previous example, I overlapped them (**PS: you might have to fool around with  `nudge_y` and `nudge_x` in `geom_text` to get them properly aligned)**  :

```
library(data.table)
library(magick)
library(ggplot2)
library(showtext)



#layer 1, upwards arrow
arrows1 = matrix(c("", "\U1F801", "\U1F801", ""),
                 nrow = 2,
                 ncol = 2)
grid_arrows1 = expand.grid(x = 1:ncol(arrows1), y = 1:nrow(arrows1))
grid_arrows1$val = arrows1[as.matrix(grid_arrows1[c('y', 'x')])]

#layer 2 , leftwards arrow
arrows2 = matrix(c("", "\U1F800", "\U1F800", ""),
                 nrow = 2,
                 ncol = 2)
grid_arrows2 = expand.grid(x1 = 1:ncol(arrows2), y1 = 1:nrow(arrows2))
grid_arrows2$val = arrows2[as.matrix(grid_arrows2[c('y1', 'x1')])]

#layer 3 , upwards arrow
arrows3  = matrix(c("\U1F801", "", "", "\U1F801"),
                  nrow = 2,
                  ncol = 2)
grid_arrows3 = expand.grid(x2 = 1:ncol(arrows3), y2 = 1:nrow(arrows3))
grid_arrows3$val = arrows3[as.matrix(grid_arrows3[c('y2', 'x2')])]

#layer 4 , leftwards arrow
arrows4 = matrix(c("\U1F800", "", "", "\U1F800"),
                 nrow = 2,
                 ncol = 2)
grid_arrows4 = expand.grid(x3 = 1:ncol(arrows4), y3 = 1:nrow(arrows4))
grid_arrows4$val = arrows4[as.matrix(grid_arrows4[c('y3', 'x3')])]

#use function font_add from lybrary showtext
 font_add("Symbola", regular = "Symbola_hint.ttf")
# Take a look at the function showtext_auto() as well

 ggplot(grid_arrows1,
        aes(x = x, y = y, label = val),
        family = 'Symbola',
        size = 18) +
   
   geom_tile(fill = 'NA', colour = 'black') +
   geom_text(
     grid_arrows1,
     mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, label = val),
     family = 'Symbola',
     size = 18
   ) +
   
   geom_text(
     grid_arrows2,
     mapping =  aes(x = x1, y = y1, label = val),
     family = 'Symbola',
     size = 18,
     nudge_x = -0.01
   ) +
   geom_text(
     grid_arrows1,
     mapping =  aes(x = x, y = y, label = val),
     family = 'Symbola',
     size = 18,
     angle = 180
   ) +
   geom_text(
     grid_arrows2,
     mapping =  aes(x = x1, y = y1, label = val),
     family = 'Symbola',
     size = 18,
     angle = 180,
     nudge_x = 0.01,
     nudge_y = 0.007
   ) +
   geom_text(
     grid_arrows3,
     mapping =  aes(x = x2, y = y2, label = val),
     family = 'Symbola',
     size = 17,
     nudge_y = 0.03
   ) +
   geom_text(
     grid_arrows4,
     mapping =  aes(x = x3, y = y3, label = val),
     family = 'Symbola',
     size = 17,
     nudge_x = -0.021,
     nudge_y = -0.01
   ) +
   
   scale_y_reverse() +
   theme_classic() +
   theme(
     panel.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent"),
     # bg of the panel
     plot.background = element_rect(fill = "transparent", color = NA),
     # bg of the plot
     axis.text  = element_blank(),
     panel.grid = element_blank(),
     axis.line  = element_blank(),
     axis.ticks = element_blank(),
     axis.title = element_blank()# get rid of legend panel bg
   ) 
 
 #save plot as image
 ggsave(filename = 'plot.png',
        device = 'png',
        bg = 'transparent')
 
 # read images with package magick
 image_read('plot.png')
```

Here is the result I got:

[image]

I cannot say this is the prettiest code ever seen, it is as hack as it gets, but it might be helpful! (It took more time to get this done than I would like to admit!)

Comment: Isn't it easier to overlay two geom_text layer instead of merging to images ?

Comment: You are absolutely right, @Billy34. I got an error earlier and didn't have the time to figure out why it was not working. But now I have edited it. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for you input, it is interesting indeed. 
However, the orthogonal arrows obtained by overlaying a horizontal and a vertical unicode arrow are not as beautiful as the original ones.
I have tried with tikz, which is very flexible to draw the set of $2^4-1$ directions, but was not able to import the tikz-arrows in R.

Comment: True, @Bertrand. I tried another approach. Still super "hacky" though...

Comment: Did you try to use the package `tikzDevice`?  https://github.com/daqana/tikzDevice

Comment: @ViviG: yes I used tikzDevice from time to time, it is helpful to add latex labels to R plots and figures, but was not able to use this package to import arrows drawn with latex...

Comment: @ViviG: I include some latex-arrows below, in case this helps...    
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
   \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
   \draw [->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}

 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
   \draw [<-] (-1,0) -- (0,0);
   \draw [<-] (0,-1) -- (0,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}
  
 \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.3]
   \draw [->] (0,0) -- (0,1);
   \draw [<-] (-1,0) -- (0,0);
   \draw [->] (0,0) -- (1,0);
   \draw [<-] (0,-1) -- (0,0);
 \end{tikzpicture}